# Codeigniter:How to get the last inserted id?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter.I need to get the last inserted id and increment it and use it in my view page,
My controller code:

```
public function add_tickets()
     {


        $status = $this->input->post("status_button");
        $emp_array = $this->input->post("employee");
        $start_array = $this->input->post("start_time");
        $pid_array = $this->input->post("pid");
        $total_array = $this->input->post("total");
        if($status == "leave_open")
        {
            $button_status="open";
        }
        else
        {
            $button_status="";
        }
       $insert_id = $this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);
      /*Here I am tring to get the last inserted id*/
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($pid_array); $i++) {
        if(isset($pid_array[$i])&& $pid_array[$i]!=""){
        $data_to_store = array(
        'id' => $insert_id +1,
        'employee' => $emp_array[$i],
         'start_time' => $start_array[$i],
         'pid' => $pid_array[$i],

         'total' => $total_array[$i],
         'status' => $button_status,
         );

        $this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);
       }
    }
    $data['ticket_new_id'] = $data_to_store['id'];
    $data['bill']=$this->billing_model->get_bill();
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/list';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

     }
```

This is my controller function where I insert my bill.
Here is my model function,

```
function store_bill($data)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('bill', $data);
         $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $insert_id;

    }
```

Here I am using `$this->db->insert_id()` to get the last inserted id.
I am getting a error like this,

```
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1174
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `$data_to_store` variable?

Comment: That is a array where I get the post value from form @AnkiiGangrade

Comment: YOue are not create any array `$data_to_store` in your code!!

Comment: Where to use? Can you please tell me @Saty

Comment: `$insert_id = $this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);` for this line where you define `$data_to_store` ??

Comment: See inside for loop I have that variable. That is not the problem I think

Comment: your loop is after `$this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store)` line. Ir means your `$data_to_store` is nothing before loop.

Comment: How to get the id from my model instead of doing this? Without inserting something inside a table can we get the last inserted id?

Comment: how we get last insert id before inserting the data into database???No way

Comment: Is there some other way? I need to get the last inserted id and use it for next id

Comment: get max id from database and max+1 will be youe next inserted id

Comment: How to do that? Can you please help me

Comment: Why you need to set the ID every time just create id field as auto increment in database it will automatically increment the Id value.

Comment: Yes it happens but I dont want it. for every item I insert them inn my table but the bill id will be the same. So I need to control the id. Can you get me? @Mitul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your solution:

```
<?php 

public function add_tickets()
     {


        $status = $this->input->post("status_button");
        $emp_array = $this->input->post("employee");
        $start_array = $this->input->post("start_time");
        $pid_array = $this->input->post("pid");
        $total_array = $this->input->post("total");
        if($status == "leave_open")
        {
            $button_status="open";
        }
        else
        {
            $button_status="";
        }

        /*beore inserting first get the last ID of the table*/

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('bill');
            $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
            $result = $this->db->get()->result();

            $last_id = $result[0]->id;//This is the last ID of the table


      /*now insert the data with incremented ID and send it to your view */




$data_to_store = array(
    'id' => $insert_id +1,
    'employee' => $emp_array,
     'start_time' => $start_array,
     'pid' => $pid_array,

     'total' => $total_array,
     'status' => $button_status,
     );


    $this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);

 $insert_id =  $last_id + 1;//this will be your last inserted ID
$data['ticket_new_id'] = $insert_id ;
$data['bill']=$this->billing_model->get_bill();
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/list';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

 }
```

For more reference how to get last ID using codeigniter check [this](http://w3code.in/2015/09/codeigniterhow-to-get-the-last-inserted-id/)

Comment: Can we have the query within controller? @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code not initialize the variable

```
    $status = $this->input->post("status_button");
    $emp_array = $this->input->post("employee");
    $start_array = $this->input->post("start_time");
    $pid_array = $this->input->post("pid");
    $total_array = $this->input->post("total");
    if($status == "leave_open")
    {
        $button_status="open";
    }
    else
    {
        $button_status="";
    }
    // $data_to_store is not initialized and you are trying to store the value that's why it give you error
   $insert_id = $this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);
```

Comment: I do that because I got that error above. I need to get my last inserted id @Mitul

Comment: You need to change table field to autoincreament

Comment: I dont want auto increament. I need the id in my control.. @Mitul

Comment: Yes it happens but I dont want it. for every item I insert them inn my table but the bill id will be the same. So I need to control the id. Can you get me? @Mitul

Comment: You will get last inserted id using Maximum function `$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `bill`')->row()->maxid;`